# pl sql query for average by month

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

It's for a school project. I got a table Consultation with the following data :

```
DoctorId integer,
PatientFile varchar2(20),
visitDate date,
Diagnostic varchar2(20) and
Prescription varchar2(20).
```

I want to create a query that will show the average number of consultation by month. I try :

```
SELECT AVG(count(*)) AS count, MONTH(dateVisit) as month
FROM consultation
GROUP BY month
```

I doesn't work : I can't use the month fonction on dateVisit.

My questions : how would you do a query that will show the average number of consultation by month ?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `count(*)` of what? That could be a clue.

Comment: I want to average the number of consultation by month so I try count(*) to count each occurance of the table. I dont know if it's possible to extract the month of the field visitDate and then sort the average by month ?

Comment: I'm investigating this on MS SQL Server 2016 right now. Hold on!

Comment: I came with an idea : select extract(month from visitDate) as month, avg(count(*)) as number from consultation group by visitDate; but I get the error  = not a single-group group function.

Comment: I'm having so many syntax errors in MS SQL management studio. *Sigh*

Comment: I think I found the solution : select avg (distinct (extract(month from visitDate))) as month from consultation;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141756/discussion-between-boggartfly-and-jean-francois-girard).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :

```
select avg (distinct (extract(month from visitDate))) as month from 
consultation;
```

So here's how it's working :
1- extract(month from table_name) as month from table_name. You can 
also put year or day instead of month.
2- distinct = will count the total for each month (instead of showing every record).
3- avg = average of each month.

Comment: Consider the case if date span over several years, e.g. April 2016 and 2017

Comment: I'm not able to resolve the case of the year. Can you show me how you would do it ?

Comment: For example `trunc(visitDate, 'MM')` or `extract(year from visitDate) || extract(month from visitDate)`